# Mapbox Icon-Image Dynamic Symbol (icon) Loading with Sprite

Tags: maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I am trying to do something I feel is very simple, yet seems that I am clearly misunderstanding a crucial piece of the mapbox `addlayer` feature.

**The Goal**

Create dynamically identified icons, based on a features data value (e.g. geojson feature data vale `title: "walmart"`). Essentially just adding dynamic store icons from the sprite image when those locations are queried via tilequery. [picture representation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ0RI.png)

**The problem**

I keep getting an error when trying to use the sprite values from the style. Error: `util.js:349 Image "airport-11" could not be loaded. Please make sure you have added the image with map.addImage() or a "sprite" property in your style. You can provide missing images by listening for the "styleimagemissing" map event.`

I see tons of resources talking about sprites, but none discuss how to exactly implement them in this fashion. I have even tried querying the sprite and then adding the values using dot notation to access sprite values. This gives an error of "undefined" and invalid value.

Example code:

```
      map.addLayer({
    id: "tilequery-points",
    type: "symbol",
    source: "tilequery", // Set the layer source
    layout: {
      "icon-image": [
        "match",
        ["get", "title"],
        ["HEB"],
        "H-E-B_logo",
        ["Pilot Flying j"],
        sprite.Pilot_Travel_Centers_logo,
        // "Pilot_Travel_Centers_logo",
        ["Dollar General"],
        "Dollar_General_logo",
        ["Cumberland Farms Corp"],
        "Cumberland_Farms_logo (1)",
        ["CEFCO"],
        "CEFCO-convenience-stores-Logo_510px",
        ["BJs Wholesale Inc"],
```

**The Question**

How do I access the sprite values and not get an error?!!!
Thanks for the help! I Wouldn't ask if I didn't need it!

**UPDATE**

I have figured out that to use sprite images inside of any layer, the images will automatically be available if you have them in your Mapbox studio sprite image collection. The confusion was that previously, I was not able to use them from link. However, it should work automatically.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

It's true the documentation about sprites is not super clear. I'll try to summarise (simplifying a bit).

A Mapbox GL style has one sprite. That's a PNG containing all the icons, plus a JSON file specifying what each icon is called (its icon ID), and where it located within the PNG. The sprite is specified by giving a URL as the `sprite` property: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sprite/

You can also add images to the sprite dynamically after the map loads, with `map.loadImage` and `map.addImage`, specifying the icon ID.

To display an icon, you use that same ID in a symbol layer: `"icon-image": "myicon"`.

You can run into trouble when you try to combine your own icons with those in a Mapbox basemap (which are Maki icons with names like `airport-11').

To combine them, you can do one of these three things:

- upload your icons to a style in Mapbox Studio
- load your icons dynamically
- generate a new sprite sheet offline, using something like [mbsprite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mbsprite)

I don't know what you meant about "dot notation", but no, that's not the right path.

Comment: Thanks for answering Steve! I understand it a bit better now, however, I am still a bit confused on the main problem here. Where do I **insert the "sprite"** link since that is going to allow me to reference those images by name inside of the symbol. 

Is it somewhere inside the symbol `addLayer` or symbol property? Or is it queried automatically by using a style? Or is it supposed to be referenced in some other way? Thanks again!

Comment: If you're creating your whole style from scratch (ie, you have a 'my-style.json' file), then it goes at the very top. Read the style specification, including the link I provided.

Comment: Understandable enough. I apologize for dragging this on, but I am really not able to understand this. I wish to use the sprite images inside of my tilequery `map.addLayer` element. 

Would you be able to look at my code in this code from this [codepen link](https://codepen.io/devinosborne/pen/KKaryBQ)? It has the exact spot that I am struggling with so we are all on all same page as to what is the exact issue at hand. If the sprite link doesn't get used in vanilla JS, or something else, how do we then reference it natively from the mapbox studio? Thanks again!!!

Comment: Please read the doc carefully. There is one sprite file *per style*. No, you can't pass a sprite to `addLayer`.

Comment: I agree with @DOZBORNE, your answer its unclear, the docs doesnt contain any specific answer for loading the sprite from external files. Thus he asked for help how to use it !

Comment: The documentation for specifying an external sprite file is here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/root/#sprite